# Pointer issue in C - what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c, pointers, dos

For a bit of background, I'm writing a meter reading application in C for a small 16-bit handheld computer that runs a proprietary version of DOS.

I have a screen that displays meter information and prompts the user to type in a reading.  When the user presses the enter key on the unit, the following code will execute:

```
/* ...
 * beginning of switch block to check for keystrokes
 * ...
 */
case KEY_ENTER: {
    /* show what has been entered */
    if(needNew == 0) {
        /* calculate usage for new reading */
        double usg = 0;
        int ret = CalculateNewUsage(vlr, buf, &usg);
        VerifyReadScreen(vlr, ret, buf, &usg);
        needRedraw = TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
/* .... end switch statement */
```

`vlr` is a pointer to a struct that holds all account/meter information, `buf` is of type `char[21]` used to store numerical keystrokes for the reading which is handled above this block.  My variables all contain valid data when I check them both before and after calling `CalculateNewUsage`.

However when I check variable data again after entering `VerifyReadScreen`, `newread` is pointing somewhere random in memory and returns what looks like a copyright notice.  The interesting thing is no matter what account or what reading I enter - the same invalid data for `newread` in `VerifyReadScreen` is printed on the screen.  I am passing the address to `VerifyReadScreen` in the same manner as `CalculateNewUsage`, but somehow I've ended up with something different.

Here is `VerifyReadScreen`:

```
BYTE VerifyReadScreen(const VLRREC * vlr,
                        const int status,
                        const char * newread,
                        const double * usage) {

    /* snip a whole bunch of irrelevant formatting code */

    printf("%s", (*newread)); /* prints funky copyright text */

    /* snip more irrelevant formatting code */
    return TRUE;
}
```

Thank you to Jefromi for pointing out that the code where I am actually printing `newread` in `VerifyReadScreen` should really read:

```
printf("%s", newread); /* yay! */
```

because I didn't need to dereference `newread` because `printf` does this for me.  I was essentially passing a pointer to a pointer which was some arbitrary place in memory.

Comment: How are `buf` and `usg` declared?

Comment: When you say "`buf` is a string", do you mean it's already a `char*`? And you're casting its address to type `const char*`?

Comment: @Alokzilla - buf is of type `char[21]` declared within the function block of the code checking for keystrokes.  usg is declared within the `case KEY_ENTER` block.

Comment: @Jefromi - No, buf is of type `char[21]` and not a pointer.

Comment: Just a thought - you've looked over your code to make sure you're not wandering out of your segment, yes?

Comment: You're also dereferencing newread (to a `char`) in `VerifyReadScreen` then providing it to printf for a `%s`. The printf's going to try to read string data from the memory address given by the first character in `newread`. Is that how you're confirming you have bad data in `VerifyReadScreen`?

Comment: I'd like to point out that other than, "what am I doing wrong here?" you haven't actually asked a question at all.  You say you're at your wits end, yet do not describe what you've considered, what you've tried, what you've ruled out, and what you still suspect.  Although your text is well written, this still is one of the worst "read-my-mind and fix-my-code-for-me" posts I've ever seen.

Comment: @abelenky: Oh, come on. Instead of "fix my code" you could read "help me find the mistake I can't see" - it does teach the OP something, since most likely she's unaware it was a mistake (it's in the code twice - not a typo), and a kind OP will edit the question afterward so that it can help someone else discover the same mistake in their code.

Comment: You got your answer, but in the function calls, you should change `(const char *)&buf` to `buf`.  The name of an array in function parameters is equivalent to a pointer to its first element.  If this makes you uncomfortable, you can use `&buf[0]` instead of `buf`, but when passed to a function, they mean exactly the same thing.  The reason `&buf` works is because on most computers, the numerical values of `&buf` and `buf` are the same.

Comment: @abelenky - I took considerable time to try to find my answer through other means before posting this here (three work days, to be exact).  I have not used C since college years ago so I'm relearning it as I go along.  I see many questions of this nature on SO, so I didn't think it was out of place.  The offending code *looked right* to me, so I didn't even consider it.  The computer I'm writing this for doesn't give you informational error messages, either garbage prints on the screen or the unit resets itself without you knowing why, so I can't really say "tried this and it gave me X error".

Comment: @Alok - Thank you for the suggestion about the function calls, it makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I'm confident enough to post this as an answer:

```
BYTE VerifyReadScreen(const VLRREC * vlr, const int status, const char * newread, const double * usage) {
...
    LCD_set_cursor_pos(19 - strlen(newread), 3);
    printf("%s", (*newread)); /* prints funky copyright text */
...
}
```

You've got a string (`char*`) `newread`, but in that printf, you're dereferencing it, which gives you the first character of the string. You then use it as the argument to a `%s` for printf, so it tries to go to the memory address given by that character and print what it finds there.

P.S. You got unlucky - generally, doing something like this is likely to give you a segfault, so you can track it down to that line and realize there's a pointer error right there.

Comment: You're right - taking out the dereferencing fixed it!  Thank you SO much! :D

Comment: I should add that I looked at that bit of code again over and over again and it didn't seem out of place at all.  These handheld computers act funny most of the time instead of giving definitive error messages when you're doing something incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't known if that's the problem you are facing, but the `buffer` used in `VerifyReadScreen`, which is 21 characters long, will most likely overflow:

```
if(strlen((*vlr).ServAdd) >= 20) {
    sprintf(buffer, "%20s", (*vlr).ServAdd);
}
```

The `%20s` format specifier doesn't prevent `sprintf` to write more than 20 characters. It just pads the string with spaces if it's shorter than 20 characters (or did you want `<= 20` in the if-condition?).

```
else {
    memset(buffer, 0x20, (int)(strlen((*vlr).ServAdd) / 2) + 1);
    strcat(buffer, (*vlr).ServAdd);
}
```

Here some padding is done depending on the strings length, but I don't see how it would make sure that the result isn't longer than 20 characters.

Comment: This code is pretty rough at this point, but this is good to know.  Thanks!